# How could I mount the app in to index.html

Tags: vue.js, cdn

I am pretty new to Vue.js.
I am trying to build a project without cli.
I've tried to add the CDN into the index.html.
and create a app.js file , add it to index.html and it works well.

Then I watch some youtube and tutorial, the idea of component kicks in and I am trying to add the Single-File Components into the project.

But I do not know how to structure the files so that it could work with the components.
Here are what I've got so far , could someone please tell me what's wrong here？

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Oren

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>new Vue project</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
         <Header /> 
    </div>   
</template>

<script>
import Header from './src/components/Header'
export default {
    name:'App',
    components:{
        Header,
    },
    data(){
        return{
            test:'oren testing'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use App.vue file. You should work with build tools like webpack or vue cli. https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

Comment: so I can't mix use the cdn and the vue cli.
I thought I am building a fairly small project so I could just use cdn.

So If I am using CDN only, I can just put all the html elements in this div in index.html?
<div id="app"></div>

Comment: You could reference this guide if you do not want to use build tools. https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools
Yes, put all html elements in app.vue into div with id="app".

Comment: @OrenLai It's not about the size of the project but the ease of use. You can't use SFC without build step. .vue files aren't spec compliant and can't be used directly in a browser

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your reply , I understand the idea now

Answer (score 0):

[SFCs require a build step](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#why-sfc) and is recomended

> When using standard Vue without a build step and mounting to in-DOM templates, it is much less optimal because:
>
> 1. We have to ship the Vue template compiler to the browser (13kb extra size)
> 2. The compiler will have to retrieve the template string from already instantiated DOM
> 3. The compiler then compiles the string into a JavaScript render function
> 4. Vue then replaces existing DOM templates with new DOM generated from the render function.

If you still don't want a build step, take a look at [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#comparison-with-standard-vue)